# How to read each and every cell's value of the row of Excel sheet if 1st and last cell value is Null or Blank?

Tags: java, excel

this is the excel sheet

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
col1 | Col2 | col3 | col4 | col5| col6| col7|   and so on
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1    | 2    |   3  |   4   |  5 |  6|    7|     and so on
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |      |   3  |   4   |  5 |   |     |     and so on
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My output should be 
Blank Blank 3 4 5 Blank Blank

I am reading this excel sheet using `Iterator<Cell>` `cell=row.cellIterator`
I want to read every cell values with Blank also but using `CellIterator` I am able to read only 3 4 5 from 2nd row.

How to read 2nd row with space also? I have also seen that If 1st cell and Last cell is not Blank then `CellIterator` successfully read the blank values also.

How to read each and every cell value of the particular row in java if first and last cell of that row is blank?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are using Apache POI for Excel manipulation.

The CellIterator will only return cells that have been defined in the file, which largely means ones with either values or formatting.

Refer to http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells

> Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells
>
> In some cases, when iterating, you need full control over how missing or blank rows and cells are treated, and you need to ensure you visit every cell and not just those defined in the file. (The CellIterator will only return the cells defined in the file, which is largely those with values or stylings, but it depends on Excel).
>
> In cases such as these, you should fetch the first and last column information for a row, then call getCell(int, MissingCellPolicy) to fetch the cell. Use a MissingCellPolicy to control how blank or null cells are handled.

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
   if (r == null) {
      // This whole row is empty
      // Handle it as needed
      continue;
   }

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```